# How to use Button in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I can't figure out how to do it in discord.py so that pressing a button reads the user who pressed it, then writes all users who pressed the button to a temporary array. And if it's not difficult if you know YouTube lessons on this, please give a link. *(translated with google translator, sorry)*

Answer (score 2):

You can add a callback function to your button for that, like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    users = []
    button  = discord.ui.Button(style = discord.ButtonStyle.primary, label="Add a user")
    
    async def button_callback(i):
        users.append(i.user)
        print(users)
    
    button.callback = button_callback
    # Need to create a view
    buttons_view = discord.ui.View()
    # and add the button component to the view
    buttons_view.add_item(button)
    # send the view with the message
    await ctx.send("Add a user by clicking the button", view=buttons_view)
```

Comment: I don't understand what "ui" is for 
button  = discord**.ui.Button**(style = discord.ButtonStyle.primary, label="Add a user"),
sorry for such stupid questions

Comment: @add It's the path for the `Button` class in `discord`.

Comment: For some reason, I don’t have such a class in `discord`, but I have a `batton` in `discord_components`

Comment: It seems you are not using `discord.py 2.0` and instead some other package for the components. My answer is for 2.0 which I  recommend. You can install it by using pip like this:  `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`. Also, here are the [breaking changes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html) in v2.